# How can we get a definitive list of everything (or nearly everything) stored in a python object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, getattribute, python-object

When I say "stored" I mainly mean attributes, not container elements or values returned by `__getitem__`.

My first thought was to bypass any overloaded `__getattribute__` method (aka, dot-operator)  with `object.__getattribute__`. I thought I would then get an objects untampered-with dictionary. However, not all objects have a `__dict__` attribute, including the built-in `list` type; The following code...

```
lyst  = list()
dct = object.__getattribute__(lyst, '__dict__')
```

... raises an attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:/python_playpen/playpen_object_dict.py", line 25, in <module>
    dct = object.__getattribute__(sidgfisdgf, '__dict__')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, `list` does have a `dir` method. The following code does not throw an error.

```
object.__getattribute__(lyst, '__dir__')()

object.__dir__(lyst)
```

Does very nearly every python object have a `dir` method?

`dir` seems to return class methods, but I want ***ONLY*** the data belonging to an object, not data belonging to a class an object is instantiated from.

Given that the following:
    obj = Klass()
    obj.foo()

is usually really:

```
obj = Klass()
Klass.foo(obj)
```

`foo` is data in `Klass`'s dictionary, not `obj`s. In order to apply `foo` to `obj` you have to pass `obj` as an input into `Klass`'s foo method. Then `Klass.foo` modifies `obj` in-place, or perhaps, only reads from `obj`.

`Klass` is presumably accessed from `obj` in two steps:

1. look-up the key (aka, a string) `__class__` in `obj`'s dictionary.
2. Search for `foo` (or whatever the method name is) in the keys of `Klass`'s dictionary

How do we get ***only*** `obj`'s dictionary entries? If one of the dictionary (key, value) pairs inside `obj` is a reference to `Klass`, that is fine, I just do not want the methods or class member variables stored inside of `Klass`. I want data (and keys) which `obj`'s dictionary points to ***directly***. 
I would call method access "in-direct" since the look-up in `obj`'s dictionary takes us to `klass`'s dictionary on our way to find the target of our search (the method `foo`).

Comment: `vars(some_object)`?

Comment: Looks like you need an introduction to the C API more than you know. You'd understand how attributes can be implemented in built-in classes, and why your question borders on the meaningless.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `vars()` gives
`TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute` for instances of the `list` class.

Comment: Yes. So? What exactly are you *expecting* from a `list` object? I don't really understand what you are expecting...

Comment: Do you consider the length of a list, or the size of the allocated buffer to be attributes? They're stored with every instance, but you can never reach them from Python code.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely evil, and doesn't give names, but ... `gc.get_referents()` is pretty close. From the docs:

> `gc.get_referents(*objs)`
>
> Return a list of objects directly referred to by any of the arguments. The referents returned are those objects visited by the arguments’ C-level tp_traverse methods (if any), and may not be all objects actually directly reachable. tp_traverse methods are supported only by objects that support garbage collection, and are only required to visit objects that may be involved in a cycle. So, for example, if an integer is directly reachable from an argument, that integer object may or may not appear in the result list.